# Can anyone explain why am i getting the same result for bitwise and and or operator in C

Tags: c

I want flip the lsb of uint from 1 to 0 and vice-versa
Can someone tell me why the below code is o/p the same result of & and | operation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
int main()
{
    uint8_t a=53;
    uint8_t x=255; //     AND BY 255 TO insert 0 at LSB position 11111110
    uint8_t y=1;   //      OR BY   1 TO insert 1 at LSB position 00000001

    uint8_t b=a&x;
    uint8_t c=a|y;

    printf("\nValue of byte a : %d",a );
    printf("\nValue of byte b : %d",b );
    printf("\nValue of byte c : %d",c );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How can the value of a, b and be the same, i.e. 53
I am using Pelles C IDE

Comment: I think you got your binary arithmetic wrong, 255 is 11111111 (LSB is 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write out the numbers in binary:

```
        a = 00010011
        x = 11111111
        y = 00000001
b = a & x = 00010011
c = a | y = 00010011
```

The bitwise or of `y` and `a` is `a`, since the least significant bit of `a` is already 1.

The bitwise and of `x` with any 8-bit number is that same 8-bit number, since all the bits of `x` are 1. If you want to set the least significant bit to 1, you need to take the bitwise and with 11111110 binary = 254 decimal. Rather than write it out, you can use the `~` bitwise operator to make the calculation.

```
uint8_t x = ~1;
uint8_t b = a & x;
```

Comment: Perfect explanation.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

`255` is `11111111` in binary. You want 254 ie `11111110`. ?

Comment: Oh i am such an idiot, didn't figure out the correct binary value.

Answer (score 2):

How to you expect to insert a 0 at the LSB by anding with all ones?

Answer (score 2):

53 in binary:  `00110101`

255 in binary: `11111111`

1 in binary:   `00000001`

So,

```
a & x = 00110101 & 11111111 = 00110101 = 53
```

and

```
a | y = 00110101 | 00000001 = 00110101 = 53
```

Answer (score 2):

You should learn some de-Morgan rules

```
X and 1 = X
X and 0 = 0
X or  1 = 1
X or  0 = X
X xor 0 = X
X xor 1 = not X   ---> this is the flipping so you need Var^1   (^means xor)
not ( X and Y) = (not X) or (not Y)
not ( X or Y ) = (not X) and (not Y)
X or Y = not ( (not X) and (not Y) )
```

Where X is the lsb of your variable.

Also 255's lsb is 1 and 1's lsb is also 1

So,

```
53 & 255 => lsb=1 because both lsb's are 1 
53 | 1 => lsb=1 because any one of the lsb's are 1
```

If you want to flip the lsb, then only lsb of the second operand need to be 1 if you use **xor**

```
Var ^ 1 ==>flips the lsb of Var
```

If you need to flip using only **and** , **not** and **or**  , then you need to use x3 or x4 more calculations(not efficient) and this is left to you as an excersize.